# Iterating Through Vectors in For Loops and Functions

Tags: r, function

I'm a beginner in R and I'm trying to create a function that takes vectors as input and returns numbers greater than 10 using for loops. I don't know why my function won't iterate through the entire vector; it only returns a single number.

```
hi <- function(x) {
  for (i in x) {
    if (i<10) {
      next
    }
  }
  print(i)
}
  
testvec1 <- c(2, 7, 10, 26, 18, 32)
hi(testvec1)
```

if I ran the code above, it returns 32.
I also tried specifying the position instead:

```
fxn <- function(x) {
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    if (x[i]<10) {
      next
    }
  }
  print(x[i])
}
  
fxn(testvec1)
```

it also only returns 32. The logic seems correct to me so I wonder if there's anything about the grammar that I did not grasp. Thank yall.

Comment: Your `print()` call is outside the `for` loop, so just prints the final value of `i`.

Comment: More generally though, there’s likely a vectorized way of doing what you want more easily and efficiently. For instance, to get all elements > 10 you could do `x[x > 10]`.

Comment: “parse” has a fairly specific meaning in the context of programming, and what you are describing is not parsing. I think you simply mean “traversing” or “iterating”.

Comment: @zephryl that makes sense! thank you so much! in this case R returns `[1] 45
[1] 23
[1] 12
[1] 15
[1] 33 ` which I don't think is a vector? I'm also trying to get it to return a vector, and am not sure if what I'm doing is a correct way

Comment: @zephryl yes! the other function i wrote `fxn <- function(x) {
  return(x[x > 10])
}`  works well. but i wanted to know what i did wrong with my previous code

Answer (score 0):

this will print and store your output as a list which you can then unlist

```
hi <- function(x) {
  for (i in x) {
    if (i<10) {
      next
    }
    print(i)
    storeoutput[[k]] <<- i
    k = k+1
  }
}

k=1
storeoutput <- list()
testvec1 <- c(2, 7, 10, 26, 18, 32)
hi(testvec1)


unlist(storeoutput)
```

Answer (score 0):

i managed to have it return a vector by adding an empty vector before the for loop inside the function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).